# Drag Image on Touch

Tags: android, drag, ontouchlistener

I want to drag an image on the screen.
how can i do this?
In my case, the image is simply download from the URL and placed on an activity.
I just want to drag this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with this -

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 10, 10, null);
}
```

And follow this [tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html). It can help you in step-by-step basis.

Comment: Thanks mate.. i will see this :)

Answer (score 1):

please download the default android drag and drop source code

[please check this code](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/)